# Unbind link when checkbox are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, bind

I have many checkbox and link. I want to activate the links if the checkbox is checked

```
$("a[id^='link-'], a.disabled").unbind("click");
$('#alljc').on("change", ":checkbox", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#link-'+this.id).bind('click');
    } else {
        $('#link-'+this.id).unbind('click');
    } 
});
```

Html example :

```
<div id="alljc">
    <form class="text-center" action="#">
        <input type="checkbox" id="6" />
        <a id="link-6" href="i-aggre.php?id=6">i m ok</a>
    </form>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't go the bind/unbind (or the more current on/off) route, and I don't even think that'd work. I'd just check the previous input's state when clicking a link and act on it that way.

Comment: Or in CSS only on modern browser: `#alljc a {pointer-events: none;} #alljc input:checked + a {pointer-events: all;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comment above, I don't think you can, or should, go the .bind()/.unbind() (or .on()/.off()) route. Instead try:

```
$('#alljc a').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).prev('input').is(':not(:checked)')) e.preventDefault()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jqevz7jw/)**

Answer (score 0):

`unbind` works to unbind the assigned click handler, it won't do anything for native functionality. Best bet is to toggle the `href` attribute (for ease, store the `href` in a `data-*` attr)

```
<a id="link-6" data-target="i-aggre.php?id=6" href="i-aggre.php?id=6">i m ok</a>
```

And the JS:

```
$('#alljc').on("change", ":checkbox", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        var href = $(this).data("target");
        $('#link-'+this.id).attr('href', href);
    } else {
        $('#link-'+this.id).attr('href', '');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try usind **preventDefault()** and **off()** check my **[DEMO Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/5zx2jjc8/)**

```
$("a[id^='link-'], a.disabled").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#alljc').on("change", ":checkbox", function(){
    var actId=$(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('a#link-'+actId).off('click');
    } else {
       $('a#link-'+actId).on('click',function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
       })
    } 
});
```